# Why should Apparent weight of the object floating in a fluid is 0?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, fluid-statics, buoyancy

The buoyant force act on the object and weight of the body act on water, so do they both cancel out?

Now one more thing weight experienced by a body is equal to reaction force acting on a body so here force acting on a body is buoyant force so apparent weight should be equal to buoyant force?

Answer (score 0):

If the object floats you are right. But "weight experienced by a body is equal to reaction force acting on a body" is not generally true, only if the body does not accelerate.
But what do you call "apparent weight"

Comment: "apparent weight " is weight inside water

Answer (score 0):

It's tautological. By definition, buoyancy doesn't count as apparent weight. This means that, for example, a helium balloon in air has negative apparent weight, as does an ice cube pulled underneath the surface of water.

Answer (score 0):

We must find correctly the action reaction pairs:

There is the buyoancy force that the water does on the object, and the force that the object does on water (it is not necessarily its weight).

There is the force that the Earth does on the object (its weight) and the force that the object does on earth.

Looking only for the forces on the object: its weight, buyoancy, and the reaction force of the bottom (if it is totally submerged).

If the object is placed below the surface, it can accelerate upwards or downwards depending on the difference between buyoancy and weight.

If the object is at rest floating, the buyoancy force balances its weight.
If the object is at rest submerged at the bottom, the sum of the normal reaction of the bottom plus the buyoancy force balance its weight.

Comment: So that means we cannot say that weight of the body is 0 when floating as it just balance out the weight because it cannot cancel out as both forces are acting on different things

Comment: The only difference from a body at rest on a solid surface is that the upward force, that balances the weight, is distributed for all the immersed body surface, instead of just a few points of contact.